# Running Spark on a Cluster of machines

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I want to run Spark on four computers, and i read theory of running Spark on cluster using Mesos, Yarn and SSH, but i want a practical method and tutorial for this. the Operating System of these machines are Mac and Ubuntu. I've written my code on IntelliJIDEA using Scala.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: There are decent docs on the Apache Spark page: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html